# usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lbsd

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

A little background for the problem I am having:

- I just migrated from Ubuntu Focal Fossa to Mint Cinnamon keeping my home in a partition
- libbsd is installed and can be used to compile some test code (I did a "Hello world" test using strlcpy in the main to verify that libbsd was usable)

Basically in order to use this project I have to use a library provided by my school (which compiled without problems in my last system) which is has a testing script that is going to run a test with its own Makefile:

```
INC=%%%%

INCLIB=$(INC)/../lib

UNAME := $(shell uname)

CFLAGS= -I$(INC) -O3 -I.. -g

NAME= mlx-test
SRC = main.c
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)

LFLAGS = -L.. -lmlx -L$(INCLIB) -lXext -lX11 -lm

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    # mac
    CC = clang
else ifeq ($(UNAME), FreeBSD)
    # FreeBSD
    CC = clang
else
    #Linux and others...
    CC  = gcc
    LFLAGS += -lbsd
endif

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ) $(LFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(NAME) $(OBJ) *~ core *.core

re: clean all
```

`mlx` would be the name of the library. For who is not familiar with this syntax (I was not) `INC=%%%%` is going to expand to `/usr/include`.
The command to compile the test binary expands to:

```
$ gcc -o mlx-test main.o -L.. -lmlx -L/usr/include/../lib -lXext -lX11 -lm -lbsd
```

which generates the error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lbsd
```

(that path expands to `usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld`)
Now, this kinda looks like a gcc configuration, in fact I saw something similar in the output of the command `gcc --version -v`, but only with `x86_64-linux-gnu` so without the "unkown" part. Also, one of the weird things is that the path that appears in the error actually does not exist in my system.
I already tried reinstalling gcc but with no different result.
I hope the description was clear enough, please let me know if you may need any other detail that I did not think of.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're chasing a lot of esoteric issues like paths to the linker and re-installing GCC, when the error message is pretty clear: the linker can't find the `bsd` library.  So the obvious information needed is, what is the path to the `libbsd` library on your system?  You didn't tell us that.  Just FYI, you should not need to add `/usr/lib` or `/usr/include` to your compile/link lines: those are default directories that are searched by default.

Comment: Concerning the `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include` those were already in the library that I have to use, but thank you I actually did not know. Concerning the path to libbsd, it is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` , but even after specifying the path it did not work. What did work was to not use the shell of VSCodium, therefore I guess there was some environmental variable of the IDE that would mess up the linker configuration (even though there was no LD_LIBRARY_PATH set)